# C++20 : Is there any subrange for left or right half range?

Tags: c++, c++20

Here's the code I'm trying to write:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<int> u (4);
    
    std::ranges::copy(v, u.begin()); // OK
    // std::ranges::copy(v + 2, u.begin()); // FAIL
    
    for (auto n : u) {
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    }
    
}
```

The question is - how can I create and pass a subrange to a range-constrained STL algorithm from the starting iterator?

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you make a [mre]? It should only be a couple of lines to demonstrate the problem. Also add the compiler error.

Comment: @cigien Sure, added. The compiler error is like 200+ lines PhD thesis, as always template-related error gives.

Comment: Do you want a [rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/rotate) or [rotate_copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/rotate_copy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standardized version yet.

Self-answer:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <std::ranges::random_access_range R>
auto left_half(R r) {
    return std::ranges::subrange(std::begin(r), std::begin(r) + std::ranges::size(r) / 2);
}

template <std::ranges::random_access_range R>
auto right_half(R r) {
    return std::ranges::subrange(std::begin(r) + std::ranges::size(r) / 2, std::end(r));
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<int> u (4);
    
    std::ranges::copy(left_half(v), u.begin());
    
    for (auto n : u) {
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    }
    
}
```

Demo : https://wandbox.org/permlink/H1PuBlfIcftx5G9Z

Answer (score 2):

You can get the left side, or right side of a range, by using [`views::take`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_view) or [`views::drop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/drop_view) respectively:

```
std::ranges::copy(v | std::ranges::views::take(2), // left side
                  u.begin());

std::ranges::copy(v | std::ranges::views::drop(2), // right side
                  u.begin());
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/88j3he).

---

In general, you can also use [std::ranges::subrange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange) which lets you create a subrange from an iterator and a sentinel value:

```
std::ranges::copy(std::ranges::subrange(v.begin() + 2, v.end()), 
                  u.begin());
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hTjYn6).

Comment: This is way more verbose than the original version of the algorithm. But thanks anyway. I'll try to define my own template function to do the job.

Comment: Ok, there might be a terser way, but I'm not sure. Also, you should definitely add a namespace alias to make the code more readable.

Comment: @frozenca Added a version that I think you'll like :)